# regex expression for (pattern1) anything (!pattern2)

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to create a regex expression that does the following:

matches (*pattern1*) followed by anything including new lines possibly as long as it does not contain (*pattern2*)

A couple of the ones I think are close are:

```
test[\s\S]+(!notme)
```

or

```
test.*(!notme)
```

I'm doing this in `perl` eventually, but I'm testing on this site:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the key is that `(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

---

I think you want to make sure `pattern2` doesn't follow `pattern1`. If so, you can use the above "trick" to get

```
/pattern1(?:(?!pattern2).)*\z/s
```

In this case, you can simplify that to

```
/pattern1(?!.*pattern2)/s
```

---

If what you really want is to capture all characters that follow up until `pattern2` or end of string, you can use

```
my ($following) = /pattern1((?:(?!pattern2).)*)/s;
```

Some might recommend the following, but I hate using the `?` quantifier modifier. It's just too fragile.

```
my ($following) = /pattern1(.*?)(?:pattern2|\z)/s;
```

---

Finally, if you want what's in between `pattern1` and `pattern2`, you can use

```
my ($following) = /pattern1((?:(?!pattern2).)*)pattern2/s;
```

Some might recommend the following, but I hate using the `?` quantifier modifier. It's just too fragile.

```
my ($following) = /pattern1(.*?)pattern2/s;
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami, these are exactly what I was looking for! I ended up using the pattern you suggested /pattern1((?:(?!pattern2).)*)/s

Answer (score 3):

Standard way of doing this:

```
/pattern1(?s:(?!pattern2).)*\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

While ysth's answer coveres the general solution, it needs an explicit pattern where the match stops. If no such pattern exists naturally, we can instead use the pattern that may not be contained in the matched string *or* the end of string as a positive lookahead:

```
/pattern1.*?(?=pattern2|\z)/s;
```

This matches

```
"foo pattern1 pattern2 bar"
#   |<------->|
```

which the other solution cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test.*?(?=notme|\z)
```

Make sure to enable the "m" (multiline) and "s" (dot matches newline) options.

Comment: m only affects what `^` and `$` match, so not applicable here

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookahead based pattern should work for you:

```
(?s)pattern1(?!.*?pattern2).*$
```

`(?s)` is used for DOTALL that makes dot match newlines as well.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/pgEOOr1RpF

Comment: When will `.*$` not match?

Comment: @ikegami: Negative lookahead is just `(?!.*?pattern2)` (it doesn't include `.*$`)

Comment: Let me rephrase: `.*$` will always match, so it's useless. Get rid of it.

Comment: Yes agreed, I added `.*$` in order to match the whole string till end, no specific purpose of that.